# Airflow Dag not running as expected

Tags: airflow

I scheduled a dag to run every Friday with cron exprsn 0 0 * * FRI. But the dag is not getting triggered. If I schedule it today will the dag run coming Friday or next Friday?

I tried changing the dag to 0 0 * * 5 still I didn't run. When I changed the expression to run every hour it got automatically triggered ay every hour. I checked for start date and ensured it is a past date. I'm not sure what the issue could be bcoz the dag ran for every hour bit not for every week.

Comment: You can see the next scheduled run date beside the DAG name on the main page.